# wordpress autocomplete from json file

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I'm trying to add a jquery autocomplete on my calculating form from a JSON file as the amount of data is not big. but I haven't any suggestion coming out and no errors are shown on the console. My js file is already called in the functions file and is loaded.

my JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#dish').keyup(function(){
    jQuery('#result').html('');
    var serachFiled = jQuery('#dish').val();
    var expression = new RegExp(serachFiled, "i");
    jQuery.getJSON('global.json', function(data){
        jQuery.each(data, function(key, value){
            if(value.name.search(expression) != -1)
            {
                jQuery('#result').append('<li class="list-dush">' + value.name + ' </li>');
            }
        });
    })
});
});
```

my JSON file that is in the same folder of my JS file

```
[{"id":"1","name":"lasagna","kilocal":"3.56"}, {"id":"2","name":"pasta","kilocal":"2.17"},........]
```

and my HTML file

```
<div id = "container-form">
        <div><label class="plate_label">Dish:</label><input type="text" name="dish_name[]" id="dish" class="dish" placeholder="Enter plate name"/></div>
        <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
            <div><label class="quantity_label">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="dish_quantity[]"  class="quantity" placeholder="Enter gram or pieces/slices" /></div>
        </div>
```

this is the script i add at the end of functions.php

```
function mysite_files() {

wp_enqueue_script('mysite-js_search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_functions/my_search.js', array('jquery'));

wp_enqueue_script('mysite-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_functions/my_js.js', array('jquery'));

wp_enqueue_style('mysite-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_functions/my_css.css');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete', '', array('jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position'), '1.8.6');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mysite_files');
```

Comment: I think the JSON file was not loaded, because from within the calling page, `'global.json'` is relative to the page URL *and not the JS file*. Try something like: `jQuery.getJSON( 'global.json' ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ){ alert( 'status: ' + status + '; error: ' + error ); } );` to confirm the JSON file is loaded or not.

Comment: you right. the file JSON is not found. so i have the JSON file in the same folder as my js now the question do i need to load the JSON file the same as the js file in the functions.php with the wp_enque_script?

Comment: Update your question by adding the PHP code you used to load the JS file, and then I'll let you know what should be done.

Comment: just updated...

Comment: Thanks. But I think in the JS file, you could simply use the full path to the JSON file. E.g. if the JS file is located at */wp-content/themes/my-theme/my_functions/*, then use `'/wp-content/themes/my-theme/my_functions/global.json'` in the `jQuery.getJSON()` call.

Comment: mmm still not finding the JSON. i want to try a new way. as the only thing a need is the name can i create an array on the jquery function and get the data from that array and append it?

Comment: Well then, visit the JSON file on your browser and copy its full URL address, and use it in the script (but exclude the protocol and domain parts; e.g. `http://example.com`). But to answer your question on the `array` thing, yes, you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). I can show sample code, if you want.

Comment: I did this code for a simple autocomplete from an array what you think about it?

Comment: Well I think you can use it if it works for you. And sorry, I didn't really notice the "*on the jquery function*" part in your previous message.

Comment: I need to ask you another favor. now the autocomplete work but I would like to adapt it to all the dynamic field. can you have a look at this post is mine too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987777/autocomplete-on-dynamic-search-field

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992193/9217760).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var m = ["lasagna","pasta",......,"fish curry"]; 

jQuery('.dish').autocomplete({
search: function(event, ui) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let w = jQuery(this).autocomplete("widget").find("div"),
      re = new RegExp("("+this.value+")", "i");
    w.html((i, html) =>

      html.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>")
    );
  },100);
},
source: m
});
});
```