# autocomplete on dynamic search field

Tags: jquery, wordpress

first of all the project i'm doing is on WordPress, I have a problem finding a solution for my calculating form, so I have a jquery file that creates an autocomplete for a search field and another jquery file that duplicate the field to a maximum of 7 and when submitted should take some numbers from the database and sum them. So my problem comes when I add new field the autocomplete work just on the first one that was loaded with the page. how can I change the autocomplete so that it could work in the dynamic field?

the autocomplete jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).on("focus", ".dish", function($) {
 var m = ["lasagna","pasta",...,"buttered fish","fish curry"]; 

if (!jQuery(this).is(".aced"))
jQuery(this).addClass("aced").autocomplete({
  source: m
});
});
```

then here my ad new field jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
var html = '<div class="add-f"><div><label class="plate_label">Dish</label><input type="text" name="dish_name[]" class="dish" placeholder="Enter plate name" /></div><div><label class="quantity_label">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="dish_quantity[]"  class="quantity" placeholder="Enter gram or pieces/slices" /><a href = "#" id = "remove" ><font color="red"> X</font></a></div> </div>';
var max_rows = 6;
var x = 1;
jQuery("#add_more").click(function(e){
    if (x <= max_rows){
        jQuery("#container-form").append(html);
        x++;
    }
});
jQuery("#container-form").on('click','#remove',function(e){
    jQuery(this).parents('.add-f').remove();
    x--;
});
});
```

and last my html part from my custome template

```
<form method = "POST">
            <div id = "container-form">
                <div><label class="plate_label">Dish:</label><input type="text" name="dish_name[]" id="dish" class="dish" placeholder="Enter plate name" ></div>
                    <div><label class="quantity_label">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="dish_quantity[]"  class="quantity" placeholder="Enter gram or pieces/slices" /></div>
                </div>
                <p />
                <p><br><input id="add_more" type="button" value="Add More"></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                    <p><br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
                    </form>
```

thanks you all for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have combined both your auto-complete and "add new field" scripts. If you look at the code, the `setupDishAc()` setups the auto-complete function.
- In the "add new field" script, I replaced the `html` variable with a `getDishHtml()` function (so that it's *easier* to set a unique ID to the "dish" `input`).
- In each dynamically-generated "dish box", the "remove" button is assigned the `remove` `class` and *not* `id`. Note that the first (static) "dish" `input` should have the `id` set to `dish`.

With that said, try this script:

```
// The code was beautified via http://jsbeautifier.org/ with 2 spaces indentation.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var dishes_list = ["lasagna", "pasta", '...', "buttered fish", "fish curry"];
  var max_rows = 6;
  var x = 1;

  // Setup Autocomplete on an element.
  function setupDishAc(element) {
    if (!$(element).is('.aced')) {
      $(element).addClass('aced').autocomplete({
        source: dishes_list
      });
    }
  }

  // Get the HTML for a "dish" box.
  function getDishHtml(n) {
    return '<div class="add-f"><div><label class="plate_label">Dish</label><input type="text" id="dish-' + n + '" name="dish_name[]" class="dish" placeholder="Enter plate name" /></div><div><label class="quantity_label">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="dish_quantity[]"  class="quantity" placeholder="Enter gram or pieces/slices" /></div><a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove" style="color: red;">&times;</a></div>';
  }

  // Add new dynamic "dish" box.
  $("#add_more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (x <= max_rows) {
      $("#container-form").append(getDishHtml(x));
      setupDishAc('#dish-' + x);
      x++;
    }
  });

  // Remove a dynamic "dish" box.
  $("#container-form").on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parents('.add-f').remove();
    x--;
  });

  // Setup for the first "dish" box.
  setupDishAc('#dish');
});
```

Try a live demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRVExM).

Comment: I'm very sorry to disturb you again but can you explain me quickly the meaning of the preventDefault()??

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp should help you understand it. But basically, in the code I provided, `preventDefault()` will prevent the browser from following the link (e.g. you won't be sent to `#add_more`; hence the browser's address bar won't have the `#add_more` hash). Comment it out and just see the browser's address bar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it's an `input` with `add_more` as its `id`, and not a link with a `href` of `#add_more`.. but what I said did apply to the second `preventDefault()` in the code, where the link's `href` is `#`.